# Остановка Ringtone, запущенного из Broadcast Reciever`a

Tags: android, android-notification, android-broadcastreceiver

Добрый день. Есть приложение, которое просматривает все полученные SMS сообщения. Если приложение выключено и в этот момент пришло сообщение, адресованное приложению, то я вывожу Notification. По нажатию Notification открывается главное активити и начинает играть Ringtone (который запущен из Notification builder`a).

**Вопрос:** Как остановить мелодию на главном экране? При открытии главного экрана, я вывожу AlertDialog с кнопкой "ОК". По нажатию на эту кнопку, я хочу останавливать музыку, но как мне получить её экземпляр, чтобы остановить??

Вот код вызова уведомления в BroadcastReceiver`е:

```
 void myNotification(final Context context){

        notificationAlarm = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    Thread.sleep(2000);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);


                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                        0, notificationIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

                Resources res = context.getResources();
                Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);

                builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notify_icon)
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.notify_icon))
                        .setTicker("Пришло новое сообщение!")
                        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(ringURI)
                        .setContentTitle("Сообщение")
                        .setContentText("Получено новое сообщение"); 

                Notification notification = builder.build();

                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);             
            }
        });
        notificationAlarm.start();
    }
```

Comment: 1. Вы пробовали просто отменить уведомление? 2. Можно поставить флаг builder.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

Comment: @AndrewGrow у меня вроде стоит флаг авто отмены - .setAutoCancel(true)

Comment: и звук не выключается при отмене?

Comment: @AndrewGrow нет, в том то и дело. Как Вы можете видеть, я запускаю уведомление в отдельном потоке и при этом жду 2000 мили секунд. Мне кажется, проблема может быть именно в этом. Это связано с тем, что в момент прихода СМС сообщения играет системное уведомление. Если в этот момент запустить мою мелодию, то она не заиграет. Поэтому я жду 2 сек.

Comment: Может преравть поток? notificationAlarm.interrupt()